# Total size of Real Racing 3 Android

Tags: android, real-racing-3

What's the total size of Real Racing 3 on Android? It says on there that it's 43MB, but when I install the apk, it still downloads on startup.

Answer (score 2):

Once you start playing, if you press "Download all resources" it needs to download 1580MB. Total aprox. size would be 1650MB.

Answer (score -1):

At the latest update during July 2017, the size on iOS is 4.8GB.